# Behavior of Poisson Integral Formula for Half Space

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve the following:

> If $g$ is bounded and $g(x)=|x|$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that $|x|\leq 1$, then $Du$ is unbounded in a neighboorhood of zero.

**Remembering that:** the problem is
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \Delta u = 0 , \  in \ \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \\
u=g , \ in \ \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \end{array}\right.
$$
and $u(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\dfrac{2x_{n}}{n\omega_{n}|x-y|^{n}}g(y)dS_{y}$.

I would be gratefull if some can give me some help.